# How to add new package version to Packagist?

Tags: php, git, github, release, packagist

I have a problem with adding a new package version to packagist.

https://github.com/skydriver/stripe-request
https://packagist.org/packages/skydriver/stripe-request

My project is on Git Hub (with webhooks), and Dev version and the first release version was successfully added to packagist, but when I try to create new release, then it's not showing on packagist... here is my git log:

```
damjan@damjan-dev:~/www/projects/stripe/new-release$ git clone https://github.com/skydriver/stripe-request.git
Cloning into 'stripe-request'...
remote: Counting objects: 38, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (29/29), done.
remote: Total 38 (delta 15), reused 21 (delta 5), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (38/38), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
...
damjan@damjan-dev:~/www/projects/stripe$ cd new-release/stripe-request/
damjan@damjan-dev:~/www/projects/stripe/new-release/stripe-request$ git add .
damjan@damjan-dev:~/www/projects/stripe/new-release/stripe-request$ git commit -m "New release"
[master fc9a023] New release
 1 file changed, 349 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 StripeRequest.php
damjan@damjan-dev:~/www/projects/stripe/new-release/stripe-request$ git push origin master 
Username for 'https://github.com': SkyDriver
Password for 'https://SkyDriver@github.com': 
Counting objects: 4, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 2.42 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://github.com/skydriver/stripe-request.git
   4ea2a02..fc9a023  master -> master
damjan@damjan-dev:~/www/projects/stripe/new-release/stripe-request$ git tag -a 1.0.2
damjan@damjan-dev:~/www/projects/stripe/new-release/stripe-request$ git push --tags 
Username for 'https://github.com': SkyDriver
Password for 'https://SkyDriver@github.com': 
Counting objects: 1, done.
Writing objects: 100% (1/1), 175 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://github.com/skydriver/stripe-request.git
 * [new tag]         1.0.2 -> 1.0.2
damjan@damjan-dev:~/www/projects/stripe/new-release/stripe-request$
```

Can someone help me ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is all working fine! (**almost**)

Your latest commit (when writing this answer) is `fc9a023dcd03cf37f8a15b978d92eb40aa8b0de8`. When I view `dev-master` version on Packagist I see the same commit hash. All is good here.

**Except for one thing!**
You've specified the `version` field in your `composer.json`. Remove it! This is why you're stuck on `1.0.0`.

Versions like `1.0.0` on Packagist correspond with tags on Github. Simply tag a commit and push it (`git push --tags`). Soon this version is known in Packagist.

PS: Packagist has some lag sometimes, can be a couple of minutes. Have some patience :)

The fact that the commit hash of `dev-master` corresponds with the latest on Github proves the hook is working.

PPS: Run `composer.phar validate` and fix everything it complains about.

PPPS: You haven't added the `composer.lock` file to git. This can (in this case) be seen as a good thing! Since it's a library, and when you enable CI to it, the CI will use the newest versions of dependencies, which can warn you of future incompatibilities. But whenever a project is *not* meant as a dependency for something else, *always* add te lock file.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jasper!

Now, all it works correctly. The problem was in the version in composer.json file.

I should to learn more about "How to use composer". :)

Thanks again!
Best regards.

Comment: Np! If you have questions about Composer, seek out `@rdohms` (on twitter) or `@seldaek` (author)! They're really nice guys. Or use SO of course :)